# How to compare data from SQL to the one in a directory using PowerShell 5.1?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

The two columns in the database `MAFN` and `Version` which when concatenated with a dot "`.`" have the (almost the)same format as the folder names in the directory.
The data in col. `MAFN` is `123`and `Version` is `1`
The folders are named like:
001234.001,
000789.011
etc.
I was able to remove the leading zeros from the directory folder names.
I was also able to concatenate the data from the two columns.

I want to compare concatenated items from the query to the (new)folder names in the directory and if they match I want to do something.

The question is how do I compare the two, the concatenated data from SQL and the folder names.

I have tried storing the data from SQL in a variable but it doesn't work. Let's say the data is stored is `$sqlData` then `Write-Host $sqlData` gives the following output
`System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow Syste m.Data.DataRow`

The code is:

```
 #SQL connection and concat columns
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Sidney9.sidney.nii" -Database "NML_Sidney" -Query "SELECT  TOP (10) MAFN,Version,(Convert(varchar(50),MAFN)+'.'+Convert(varchar(50),Version))
FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[vNML_MAFN_CNCP_ByPartResource]"

#Split, trim, and join folder names to match concated data from SQL
$aidLibPath = "C:\Users\userName\Desktop\CNC_Transfer_Test_Folders\AidLib_Test\*"
Get-Item -Path $aidLibPath | ForEach-Object{
$splitFileName = $_.Name.Split('.')
$trimSplitFileName = $splitFileName.trimstart("0")-join(".")
write-host $trimSplitFileName
}
```

Basically, how do I store the data in a variable and loop over them to compare them?

I am using MSSQL 2005 and PowerShell 5.1 with SQL Server and SQLPS modules loaded.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're selecting 10 records from the database, and any number of folder names. Are you trying to return a set where there is an exact match between the two? I can tell you things like `System.Data.DataRow` means that the variable is an object and you need to use further functions to scroll through the object and pick a specific column.

Comment: Can you also edit your code sample and include what you are doing with the `$sqlData` variable

Comment: This link shows sample syntax required to dig into the results of `Invoke-SQLCmd` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-7--capture-data-into-a-dataset-object

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid only 10 rows are selected because I don't want the whole data to be displayed while I work on the script. This table probably has 1000+ rows in it. Once the code is final I will remove this condition from the query.

Comment: Just trying to understand if you have 2000 rows in the table and 53 folders to compare to, what is the required output? I guess if 32 match you want to run something 32 times?

Comment: The other question is: in the _do something_ part, do you need data matching from other columns? Because it's proabbly easier if you just conver one column of data into an array, then compare that to your folder array

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation in TSQL is not required if you have a nice scripting language like PowerShell available.

How I would do this given the sql returns the values desired:

```
#SQL connection and concat columns
$dbResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Sidney9.sidney.nii" -Database "NML_Sidney" -Query "SELECT  TOP (10) MAFN,Version
FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[vNML_MAFN_CNCP_ByPartResource]"

$dbFolders = $dbResult | ForEach-Object { "$( $_.MAFN ).$( $_.Version )" }

#Split, trim, and join folder names to match concated data from SQL
$aidLibPath = 'C:\Users\userName\Desktop\CNC_Transfer_Test_Folders\AidLib_Test'
$folders = ( Get-ChildItem -Path $aidLibPath -Directory ).Name | Where-Object { 
    $_.IndexOf( '.' ) -gt 0 } | ForEach-Object {
        $parts = $_.Name -split '.'
        "$( $parts[0].TrimStart('0') ).$( $parts[1].TrimStart('0') )"        
}

# compare the lists to see what the intersect is
$result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $dbFolders -DifferenceObject $folders -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent

if ( $result ) {
    $result.InputObject
}
```